# Multer, node.js : memory isn't purged after image upload and process

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I use Sharp and Multer in Node.js and I've got some memory problem. The buffer used doesn't seem to be released when the process is done with this code :

```
var storage = multer.memoryStorage(),
  upload = multer({
      storage: storage
  }).single('picture');

router.post('/save', function (req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
      sharp(req.file.buffer)
          .resize(400, 400)
          .max()
          .toFormat('jpeg')
          .toFile("public/images/picture.jpg", function (err) {
              res.send(true);
          });
  });
});
```

Everytime I send a picture, the memory used is augmented by the size of the picture and is never purged.

I tried without using Sharp (so basically just sending a file without processing it afterward) but the problem remains.

If users upload a large amount of files, I'm afraid it will use a tremendous amount of RAM.

What can I do to improve this piece of code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related with multer memory storage. Your image is stored in memory. After you upload image, memory should be cleared by garbage collector. But this may not become immediately. If it is available in memory after significant amount of time, then possibly there is memory leak and you should report it in https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/ .

Additionaly in multer documentation there is:

> WARNING: Uploading very large files, or relatively small files in large numbers very quickly, can cause your application to run out of memory when memory storage is used.

Maybe it is better for you to use disk storage? It will be a little slower but more reliable.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, only I'm not using memory storage.